# Android development - Users updating app question

Tags: android, file

I've written a program that, when completed, I plan to add to the Android Marketplace.  I have given many files as features for users to store information and reload later, and while debugging, I've noticed the files tend to get deleted when I update the code after a long while (like a few days spread apart--for some reason, it doesn't happen when I update the code often, like every hour when I'm adding new features and testing them out).  Note that I use a real phone for testing and not the emulator.  What I'm wondering is, will the files get deleted after each release of the app?

I really don't want users to lose their stored information on every update or bug fix I provide, so if that is the case, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope the files doesn't get deleted automatically, but it depends upon where you are storing the files. If the user deletes the app the files associated with it will get deleted too. But in case of an upgrade, No! normally it won't.

In case you are using SQLite for storing data, there is a proper way to handle upgrade there.

Comment: That's great to know! I was worried it would happen to them since it keeps happening to me while updating the code.  I just use regular Android files, with the MODE_PRIVATE flag.